# Java: pass the method result again as method parameter

Tags: java

I have one doubt if this is or is not a good practice.

So immagine that you need to concatenate not defined number of arrays, and then at the end print the result. So immagine that you can call calculate a lot of times.
E.g.

```
Object[] example = new Object [0];

public Object methodAppend(Object[] a, Object[] b){
   - here append the array b to the array a 
   - return the array a
} 

public Object calculate(){

    Object[] someArray = new Object[5]
     // immagine i already have some values in the array
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
       example = methodAppend(example,someArray)

    return example
}
```

I get the wanted result. But my questions are:

1. Is this

   > example = methodAppend(example,someArray)

   a good practice?
2. How is called when I send the result of the method again in the
   method?
3. Is this one example of recursion?

Because for recursion I always thought that is when e.g. for result we call the method again.

tnx

Comment: No, it's not recursion. You might call this "accumulation", but really, applying an operation repeatedly is a very common practice. Not sure why you find this to be very special. It's like adding up all the numbers in an array by using `result = result + a[i]`.

Comment: Tnx for the answer, and yes, i didnt express myself good in the question.... wanted to ask if it was a good practice to concatenate an array in this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Is this bad practice?**

Absolutely not. This pattern is widely used and accepted just like any form of `x = x + someCall()`

2. **How is called when I send the result of the method again in the method?**

   - method call is evaluated using *current value* of your variable.
   - method result is set as *new value* of your variable
   - on next iteration, the value from last call is now *current value*
   - . . .
3. **Is this one example of recursion?**

No. It would only be recursive, if you'd call `someMethod()` from *within* `someMethod()` like

```
public int someMethod( int i) {
  if(i < 2) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return someMethod(i-1)+someMethod(i-2);
  }
}
```